# require js beginner - dependency injection

Tags: requirejs

I'm a beginner with require js and I have a doubt here.

My files are structured like below:

```
root
|____assets
|____bootstrap-3.0.1
|________dist
|____________js
|____________bootstrap.min.js
|________js
|________angulajs.min.js
|________app.js
|________jquery.min.js
|________underscorejs-min.js
|____________app
|________________main.js
```

My app.js file is like below:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "assets/js",
    "paths": {
        ": "app",
        "jquery": "jquery.min",
        "jquery-migrate": "jquery-migrate.min",
        "twitter-bootstrap": "../bootstrap-3.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min",
        "underscore": "underscore-min"
    },
    "shim": {
        "twitter-bootstrap": {
            deps: [ "jquery" ]
        }
    }
});

requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

My main.js is like below:

```
define([ "jquery", "twitter-bootstrap" ], function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#teste").tooltip();
    });
});
```

My question is about the main file and the dependency jquery in the case of bootstrap. If I had declare that the Bootstrap depends on jQuery I still have to include "jquery" in define function?
I tried to remove "jquery" declaration but the dependency was not injected and I received a **undefined** error.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it like this is really the way to go:

```
define([ "jquery", "twitter-bootstrap" ], function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#teste").tooltip();
    });
});
```

In the code above, it is clear that `$` should be bound to the `jquery` module. If you do this:

```
define(["twitter-bootstrap" ], function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#teste").tooltip();
    });
});
```

You are binding `$` to the `twitter-bootstrap` module. This won't work without further configuration because `twitter-bootstrap` exports nothing. (It installs itself as a jQuery plugin.) You could work around it by setting your shim like this:

```
"shim": {
     "twitter-bootstrap": {
         deps: [ "jquery" ],
         exports: '$.fn.tooltip',
         init: function ($) { return $; }
     }
 }
```

However, I don't recommend this since someone who comes across the code without knowing the context (that is, not knowing the relationship between the `jquery` and `twitter-bootstrap` modules) won't readily know what is going on.

In the shim above the `exports` field is not absolutely necessary but it help RequireJS know when Bootstrap has been loaded. It should be a symbol that does not exist *prior* to Bootstrap being loaded but exists *after* it is loaded.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Louis.
I´m still beginning with RequireJS and for me seems right that the if I declared jquery as a dependency for twitter-bootstrap, the module should load the dependencies before add the plugin. But, as I said, I´m beginning.